# Password protect a directory in IIS 7 (.Net MVC 2)

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a web application built in .NET MVC 2. I'd like to protect a directory with a password (basic authentication). In IIS 6, I'd simply go to the directory in security settings and remove anonymous.

But in IIS 7, I can't get it to work.

In the root of the website in authentication, I enabled anonymous because I want anyone to visit the website. Obviously.

Then I go to the MVC directory I want to protect (Views/Admin) and disable anonymous while enabling basic authentication. This doesn't work. I tried authorization rules but it didn't work either.

Is this because MVC uses sort of routing? I mean, the views/admin folder is actually website.com/admin which is, I suppose, kind of a virtual directory.

So, how to setup a password protected sub-directory in .NET MVC 2 on IIS 7?

Thanks

Stephane

Comment: Is this an actual directory that isn't an MVC route? Is the site configured in a pool running in Integrated Pipeline mode?

Comment: Folks...this is not a question for Web Masters. Please go and read their FAQ. This appears to be about securing an ASP.NET route and has an ASP.NET MVC solution.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon this...

You need to add the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to either your Controller to protect the whole thing or specific Action methods.

As described in the [ASP.NET Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), when this Attribute is encountered during the request, it will check to see if the user is properly authenticated and properly authorized in a role to access the Controller or Action.  If not, it will request authentication from the user.